# JSoup Set Proxy IP during crawling

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup

I have written a code that crawls through the site using Jsoup and the code is working absolutely fine.

The website which I am crawling has different information on the page when accessed on my Local (India IP) and some different information when accessed via my hosted server (US Ip). Is there any way I can set the proxy setting so that it appears to be hitting the site from India from the server too.

Answer (score 3):

JSoup uses the [`java.net.HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class to create web connections. That class uses [system properties to configure proxy connections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html#Proxies).

Assuming you have an HTTP/HTTPS web proxy running on `myproxyhost` port 80, you could do the following:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxyhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myproxyhost");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "80");
```

This will cause subsequent `Jsoup.connect()` calls to make the HTTP/HTTPS request via the proxy, instead of connecting directly.